# Macro still running after (Msgbox vbyesno) If Then Else statement

Tags: excel, vba

I got a problem with msgbox if/then/else statement, where I wanted to have 3 options, first if there is no sub's in a folder to have an info (I did it), second option is if there is some sub's to have an options Yes (to use macro further) and No (simply to cancel the action). But in my case, both Yes/No are doing the same, Macro is doing its action...I tried lots of ways but I am out of options and nerves...  (I got basic knowledge of VBA, mostly using google and here, so I am not skilled so much - so adapt your programming language to understand it better).

```
Sub Schaltfläche1_Klicken()
    Dim FileSystem As Object
    Dim HostFolder As String

    ' *** Folder with systems to define (path) ***
    HostFolder = "C:\Users\MirzaV\Desktop\Original"

    ' *** If folder is empty/full message ***
    Dim fs, strFolderPath, oFolder
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    strFolderPath = "C:\Users\MirzaV\Desktop\Original" ' *** This is your folder to define ***

    Set oFolder = fs.GetFolder(strFolderPath)
    If (oFolder.SubFolders.Count = 0) Then
        ' * Folder is Empty *
        MsgBox "Folder is empty!", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Information!" 
    Else
        ' * Folder isn't empty *
        MsgBox "Folder not empty! Proceed with Macro?", vbYesNo + vbInformation + vbDefaultButton1, "Information!"
    End If

    Set fs = Nothing

    Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    DoFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(HostFolder)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: You do nothing to stop the macro if the user answers *No*. You have to write code to not continue if they choose not to do so. There's no magic that makes it stop on its own; you have to write the code to do things differently based on the user's choice.

Comment: Yes, I donno to write it. I copied from tons of sources to write this code.

Comment: MsgBox returns a value. You need to use it. The problem you have when you *copied from tons of sources to write this code* is that you don't learn how the code works; all you learn is how to copy/paste. Read the documentation for MsgBox, and figure out what it returns and make an effort to write the code yourself. You'll learn much more doing so. It's better to write your own code than to depend on finding and copying the code of others in order to get things done.

Comment: I am trying man, not actually copy / paste all the time, but trying my best, I am completely new into VBA. And there lots of stuff that I dont get. 

But thank you for suggest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just replace this line:

```
MsgBox "Folder not empty! Proceed with Macro?", vbYesNo + vbInformation + vbDefaultButton1, "Information!"
```

... with these two lines:

```
yourAnswer = MsgBox("Folder not empty! Proceed with Macro?", vbYesNo + vbInformation + vbDefaultButton1, "Information!")
If yourAnswer = vbNo Then Exit Sub
```

The first line stores the user answer - returned as `Integer` by the `MsgBox` into the variable `yourAnswer`. The second line, `If yourAnswer = vbNo`, will just `Exit` the `Sub`.

Comment: Great! Thank you, such a simple stuff. Helped me so far!